# jquery adding all icons to list-divider when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, phonegap

I have a phonegap app using jquery, it's built around listview, and uses some custom js to open & close specific list-dividers based on user input.

It does everything I want with all list-dividers having text only, however when I need to include an image it goes wrong. When first opened it looks fine, but once you click to expand the divider - and from that point onwards, it adds a line of what I think are jquery icons in white above the image (X, >, <, up-arrow, down-arrow, tick, cogwheel, refresh-symbol).

When I open the app in Firefox it's fine. but if I open it in Firefox's Develor Tools emulating a phone, the problem is there. And it's there once the app is actually on a phone.

[image: example of the problem]

This is the html

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="library" data-icon="false" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="c">


<li data-role="list-divider" data-link="coffee" class="fontbrush"><div> Custom Tokens<img src="img/sample image.jpg"> </div></li>
<li class="lazy hidden coffee"><a></a>
<p><img data-src="img/luxury card.jpg">
```

and this is what I think is probably the relevant JS

```
 // hide and show on search
$(function(){
  $('[data-role="list-divider"]').toggle(function(){
    $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).addClass('show');
    $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');
$(".lazy.show").each(function(idx){    
var $img = $(this).find("img");
var src = $img.data("src");
$img.prop("src", src);
$(this).removeClass('lazy');
});

  },function(){
    $('.'+$(this).attr('data-link')).removeClass('show');
    $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
  });
});
```

With just text there's no problem. It's only when an image is there.

Any ideas?

edit: problem showing up every time an image is present, not just when there is text too

Comment: please create a working snippet that replicates your problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, although I'm still not sure what the problem was.

The code I originally took and adapted used a lot of .removeClass('ui-icon-plus') and .addClass('ui-icon-minus') to trigger changes in the list dividers and their children. I changed those to a pair of unique class names that don't reference icons. And it fixed the problem. No idea why. But it did!